# Jackson Writer object missing characters during serialization

Tags: java, json, multithreading, serialization, jackson

Jackson writer misses characters 
for instance:

as you can see the first "value" property has a "case" attribute while the second one doesn't

```
"value" : 
{
    "case" : 0.9992928025068476,
    "unit" : 0.0012222687181184695,
    "revenue" : 0.0019201603131782656,
    "cost" : 4.066965790792624E-9,
    "margin" : 0.0012176183516316138
  },
  "value" : {
    "0.9999990.9999999964045203,
    "unit" : 1.679374899388513E-7,
    "revenue" : 1.7145802215154812E-7,
    "cost" : 7.49609082287828E-18,
    "margin" : 1.6790001622333746E-7
  },
```

How can this happen?
My environment is multi-threaded and the serialization of JSON files happens in parallel.
ObjectReader & ObjectWriter are immutable so they are thread-safe and Mapper is not touched after static initialization...

The class code is as follows:

```
 public class JsonFileRepository
    {
        private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        private final ObjectReader reader;
        private final ObjectWriter writer;
        static
        {
            AnnotationIntrospector jaxbIntrospector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
            mapper.setDeserializationConfig(mapper.getDeserializationConfig()
                    .withAnnotationIntrospector(jaxbIntrospector));
            mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                    .withAnnotationIntrospector(jaxbIntrospector));
            mapper.configure(
                    org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE,
                    false);
            mapper.configure(
                    org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT,
                    true);  

        }


        public JsonFileRepository(String entityType, Class clazz) {

            this.reader = mapper.reader(clazz);
            this.writer = mapper.writerWithType(clazz);
    ...
```

**EDIT**
I serialize 70 entities, and it happens randomly approximately  2 times per run. Each time in different files, though the run is the same!

**UPDATE**
Moving from Jackson to Gson eliminated this behavior. So it is definitely either a wrong usage of Jackson on my behalf or a bug in Jackson

** FINAL UPDATE **
I was able to produce similar phenomena via Gson (though much less frequently), 
FINALLY I found the problem was indeed a multithread issue not related to the serialization package. Two threads were writing to the same file.

Comment: Can you provide some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ideally a short but complete example...

Comment: Most code is already in the question, the only thing I can add is that I use writer.writeValue(file, entity);  where entity is a simple POJO. Mimic a multi-threaded envioroment that I suspect as the problem is too much for a stackoverflow question. I am interested in understanding if I am using the Jackson API in the wrong way or not....

Comment: From what you have posted there is nothing strange. The only way it could be a multi theading issue is if you were writting to same JsoNGenerator from multiple threads. You can also check the behaviour with [Genson lib](http://code.google.com/p/genson/), I would be curious to see if you have the same problem...

Comment: I wonder which Jackson version you are running? Does this problem always reproducible?

Comment: Show us your POJO too.

Comment: I use version 1.9.13. The POJO is complex. I just posted a snippet of the JSON it provides.

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticeThreadSafety